# Let be $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ a region and $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function in $D$, we denote $f=u+iv$...

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ a region and $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function in $D$, we denote $f=u+iv$. Let be $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ a open set with $f(D)\subset G$. Suppose that $\Phi:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a function of $C^1$ class in $G$ such that his partial derivates $\Phi_u(w)$ and $\Phi_v(w)$ they are not both zero, where $w=u+iv$. If for all $z\in D$, $\Phi(u(z)+iv(z))=c$, with $c$ a constant, show that $f$ is a constant function in $D$.

---

I really don't know how to start this exercise, but I try start with the definition of complex-differentiability of $f$ (because $f$ is holomorphic function) but this not conduct me to nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial(\Phi\circ f)}{\partial z}&=\dfrac{\partial c}{\partial z}\\
\dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z}(f(z))\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}&=0\\
\left|\dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z}(f(z))\right|\cdot\left|\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right|&=0
\end{align*}
but $\left|\dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z}(f(z))\right|\ne 0$, so $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$, and hence $f$ is constant.